# Why does water follow the spoon's surface?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, surface-tension, adhesion

Why does water follow the spoon's surface?

Is the reason surface tension, viscosity effects, a pressure gradient?

[image]

Comment: Almost definitely surface tension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant forces are adhesion (the attractive force between dissimilar molecules) and cohesion (the attractive force between similar molecules). Adhesion sticks the water molecules close to the metal-water interface to the metal. Cohesion sticks the water molecules far from the metal-water interface to the water molecules close to the metal-water interface.

Surface tension (the bulk force difference between the air side of the air-water interface, where there is no cohesion force, and the water side of the air-water interface, where there is a cohesion force) plays a minor role: it keeps the shape of the stream roughly dome shaped.

Comment: if bore tiny  hole at spoon at 1/4 chord and meassure static pressure,will manometar read lower pressure than atmosphere pressure?